# How to add country, state and city select field in laravel forms?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel

Hi i am new to laravel framework in my form their will be a three fields country, state, city in select option.how can i implement these fields in laravel framework.can anyone suggest me on this.

Thanks

Comment: Not sure how this was labeled as to broad.  It is pretty specific.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a drop-down list with laravel using the `Form` class:

```php
echo Form::select('country', array('US' => 'United States', 'UK' => 'United Kingdom'));
```

Check it out for more information here: http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/html#drop-down-lists